# Angular 2: View not updating on array push

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have two child components. They are sharing data from a json file that I am loading using the http.get/subscribe method. For some reason, when I push data into the array, it doesnt update in the view. It shows the updated array in the console though.

app component loading the data from a service

```
this.dataService.getData()
 .subscribe(
     data => {
       this.data = data;
     },
     (err) => console.log('Error: ', err),
     () => console.log("success!")
   );
```

I am using inputs to access the data in my child component. Are there any ways in Angular 2 to update the view when new values are pushed into the array.

**Display Component**

```
<div *ngFor="let i of items; let k = index"><h1>{{i.title}}</h1> <p>{{i.desc}}</p></div>
```

**The Button Component**

```
<button (click)="addItem(i)">Add Item</button>

The Component Function
addItem(i){
  let data = {title: "Some title", desc: "Some desc"};
  this.data.list[i].items.push(data);
}
```

Comment: What is `dataService`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It's an angular service

Comment: Can you show us the component code?  What you posted looks correct; the problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: More details please :D what API does it call to get the data?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  the dataService does this `getData() {
    return this.http.get('data.json')
          .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }`. Then I call it in my app component. I use the @Input() to access the data in the child component. I have a button that runs a function that pushes data into an array.

Comment: @chrispy The component code for the button goes like this `addItem(i){ let data={name: "some name", desc: "some desc"}; this.data.tasks[i].items.push(data); } `

Comment: are you using the OnChanges lifecycle hook?  You might need to call that if you're doing some more work on the update to "data" :)

Comment: @chrispy I tried OnChanges on the display component, and it didnt work. I have two components. The button component and the display component which will display the update array elements. They are sibling components. I notice the html update, but the data is blank.

Comment: I would just log every step of the process and find out where the data isn't set properly.  Unless I see more code, I'm not certain what's wrong.

Comment: @chrispy I noticed that it does load the updated array after I click another button. Its very weird.

Comment: @SteveG. I added the code that I am using. A display component to display the data, and a button to push data into the array.

Comment: `ngFor` iterates over `items` not `data`

Comment: The code/question is still a bit confusing...  How about you fork this plunker to explain a little more? https://plnkr.co/edit/o2YWJVvYiGxP1NmAMRRN?p=preview

Comment: @SteveG. Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do!

Comment: @SteveG.The i was an index in my parent array. I guess my issue is for some reason, my view wont update unless I click one of the buttons I have in my navigation.

Comment: @SteveG. I did fix my problem. Now, everything works great! Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why angular 2 ngOnChanges not responding to input array push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223582/why-angular-2-ngonchanges-not-responding-to-input-array-push)

Answer (score 12):

I have the same problem and I solved this by using spread operator to create a new array of the object rather than to push new element into an existing array.

in your case I would do something like:

```
addItem(i){
  let data = {title: "Some title", desc: "Some desc"};
  this.data.list[i].items = [...this.data.list[i].items, data];
}
```

Comment: isn't that the same idea of "concat" ?