# deep checking for change similar to $watchCollection in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-observables, ngonchanges, angular2-docheck

I'm using an array of objects which I'm passing from my parent component to child components. 
When a new item is pushed to the array or the property of one of the existing objects in the array changes it does not trigger the `ngOnChanges` for the components that are using this variable (parent/child/sibling components).

In AngularJS we had `$watchCollection` using which we could keep watch on the complex objects. Do we have something similar for Angular2+?

How to do deep checking similar to `$watchCollection` in Angular2 +?

I'm familiar with AngularJS but not Angular2 +.

**UPDATE:**
Following @Shirish Patel's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43223700/2642351), I found that although the change in the variable gets reflected everywhere but the `ngOnChanges` function does not get triggered. Why is it so? I need to get this function triggered so that I can handle other operations on change of the value.

Comment: this [stackoverflow lin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223582/why-angular-2-ngonchanges-not-responding-to-input-array-push)k might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Dont push objects to your array as mutating things will not trigger ngOnChanges lifecycle hook. Sort of like rxjs distinctUntilChanged, needs a new array not a modified one.

You need to provide the inputs a new version of your array try:

`this.array = [...this.array, itemWhichNeedsAdding]`

The above returns an new instance of an array and will trigger change detection.