# Angular 8: ngx-chips form validation issue

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

I'm using `ngx-chips` in one of my Angular 8 project. When I was in the "edit" form (ngForm), I see the `tag-input` has the name of Genre which is selected. However, I'm unable to submit the form as it show me "Field is required". See below my code is `.html` file:

```
<tag-input name="itemno" #itemno="ngModel" [ngModel]="genreIds" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true" required placeholder="" class="form-control none">
    <tag-input-dropdown [autocompleteItems]="itemsAsObjects">
    </tag-input-dropdown>
</tag-input>

<div *ngIf="contentStandalonrFrm.submitted && itemno.invalid">
    <div *ngIf="itemno.errors.required" class="text-danger">{{required_field}}</div>
</div>
```

In the `.ts` file:

```
listArray.forEach(item => {
    this.genreIds.push({ 'value': item.genreId, display : item.genreName });
});
```

when I console `this.genreIds`, it shows me the below:

`{value: 36, display: "Animation"};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngx-chips components change detection is not triggered when you push the value using push method.

> Angular change detection only checks object identity, not object
>   content. Inserts or removals are therefore not detected

**Try this:**

```
const selectedValue =  listArray.map(item => {
   return { 'value': item.genreId, display : item.genreName };
});

this.genreIds = selectedValue;
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223582/why-angular-2-ngonchanges-not-responding-to-input-array-push)

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-chip-dropdown-test-bhhnlx)

Comment: I've updated my question. can you plz update your answer based on it?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: The `console.log(this.genreIds);` shows the following: 
`0: {value: 36, display: "Animation"}`

Comment: Working well as you suggested.