# Input property is undefined in custom validator function - Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following form with custom validators:

```
this.Form = this.fb.group({
      cruiseId: new FormControl(this.leg.cruiseId),
      startDate: new FormControl(this.leg.startDate, [Validators.required]),
      endDate: new FormControl(this.leg.endDate)
    }, { validators: [this.checkDuplicates, this.checkDates] });
```

In my component, I have an input property which contains all departure dates for a cruise (`@Input() cruiseArray!: cruiseItem[];`). Using the checkDuplicates function, I want to verify that we don't have 2 identical departure dates for the same cruise.

```
checkDuplicates(group: FormGroup) {   
    console.log(this.cruiseArray);
    let sDate = group.get('startDate')?.value;
    if (sDate !== null && this.cruiseArray.find(x => x.startDate === sDate))
    {
      return { invalidDuplicate: true }
    }       
    return null;
  }
```

My concern is that `this.cruiseArray` is alway undefined.
If I try  the following in my component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.cruiseArray);
  }
```

it works perfectly and my array returned by the parent is populated.

Full code:

```
  @Component({
      selector: ..,
      templateUrl: ..,
      styleUrls: [..]
    })
    export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
      Input() cruiseArray!: cruiseItem[];
    
    ....
    ngOnInit(): void {
            console.log(this.cruiseArray); <--- DOES WORK
          }
    ....
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {       
    this.createForm();
  }
    ....
      createForm() {
        this.Form = this.fb.group({
              cruiseId: new FormControl(this.leg.cruiseId),
              startDate: new FormControl(this.leg.startDate, [Validators.required]),
              endDate: new FormControl(this.leg.endDate)
            }, { validators: [this.checkDuplicates, this.checkDates] });
      }
    
    ....
    
      checkDuplicates(group: FormGroup) {   
            console.log(this.cruiseArray); <--- DOES NOT WORK
            let sDate = group.get('startDate')?.value;
            if (sDate !== null && this.cruiseArray.find(x => x.startDate === sDate))
            {
              return { invalidDuplicate: true }
            }       
            return null;
          }
      }
    }
```

Why `this.cruiseArray` is undefined in my validator function even when it is populated elsewhere in my component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validator function is inside the class, 'this' keyword inside the validator does not point to the class object, so binding the class object with the method should solve the problem

```js
validators: [this.checkDuplicates.bind(this), this.checkDates]
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to check that property :

```
 @Input() cruiseArray: !: cruiseItem[];

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes['cruiseArray']) {
        this.checkDuplicates(group: FormGroup)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Same result, the input property is still undefined. My createForm is called by ngOnChanges.

Answer (score 0):

Use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (more info [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/)), or assign `cruiseArray = [...]` in parents component.
If you use `cruiseArray.push()` or `cruiseArray.pop()` in parents component, it won't trigger `ngOnChanges` (same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223582/why-angular-2-ngonchanges-not-responding-to-input-array-push)).

Moreover, if you have multiple `Input()`, you should call `this.createForm()` with condition:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['cruiseArray']) {
        this.createForm();
    }
}
```