# Custom validator causes a lot of errors and breaks an application

Tags: angular

I was developing a test application and had one problem with validation. I have created form and binded it with FormGroup object:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addOrEditSensor()">
      <div class="block">
        <p
          [ngClass]="((name.errors?.required && name.touched) || (name.errors?.maxlength)) ? 'error' : 'error hidden'"
        >
          Fill this field. Length should be less then 30 symbols
        </p>
        <div class="input-block">
          <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
          <input class="input_text" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
        </div>
      </div>
...
```

```
  private fillForm(){
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(this.sensor.id),
      name: new FormControl(this.sensor.name, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]),
      model: new FormControl(this.sensor.model, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]),
      range_from: new FormControl(this.sensor.range_from, [Validators.required]),
      range_to: new FormControl(this.sensor.range_to, [Validators.required]),
      type: new FormControl(this.sensor.type, [Validators.required]),
      unit: new FormControl(this.sensor.unit, [Validators.required]),
      location: new FormControl(this.sensor.location, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(40)]),
      description: new FormControl(this.sensor.description, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(200)])
    })
  }
```

All standart validation works correctly, like that:
[image]

And now i got a new task. I have number inputs 'range from' and 'range to' and i have to create a custom validator, which checks if from less then to. So i created a custom function and added this validator:

```
  checkRange(control: FormControl){
    if (control.value >= this.form.value.range_to){
      return {invalidRange: true}
    }
    return null
  }
```

```
range_from: new FormControl(this.sensor.range_from, [Validators.required, this.checkRange])
```

And after that my modal breaks and I got a lot of errors and my form is undefined:
[image]

Comment: The validator function is inside the class ?

Answer (score 0):

verify that the valitor function **is not inside** the class .
to get the value use that syntax

```
this.form.controls['your form control name'].value
```

Comment: oh, it shouldn't be in class, didn't know that, thank you

Comment: so, how to realize this function if it will be not in class, can u help me?

Comment: i made something like that: `                                                                                     function checkRange(to: number): ValidatorFn{
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string] : boolean} | null => {
    if (control.value !== undefined && (isNaN(control.value)) && control.value >= to){
      return {'invalidRange': true}
    }
    return null;
  }
}` but form doesn't works anyway and i get errors

Comment: See this link and tell me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74573880/input-property-is-undefined-in-custom-validator-function-angular#74574049

Comment: and what ? i can't understand, now my function is not inside the class https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471770/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-custom-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-formgroup-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-undefined

Comment: Just verify that You call the fillForm in the ngOnint , I type for you how to get the value from form ..and in the link you found the bind method to use the validators function outside the class..

Comment: no, i call this function in ngOnChanges

Comment: Your question is like the question in the link that I send to you just focus and will be ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249932/discussion-between-matvey-androsyuk-and-chady-baghdadi).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mK0CX-68hBE&ab_channel=CodeShotsWithProfanis  this video helped me