# Adding Rows to a dynamic HTML Table in Angular is blanking out the previous rows

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, datatables

I have a nice simple HTML table with three columns:

```
 <table >
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <td class="tdBorderEmail"><label>Action</label></td>
            <td class="tdBorderEmail"><label>First Name</label></td>
            <td class="tdBorderEmail"><label>Last Name</label></td>
            <td class="tdBorderEmail"><label>Email</label></td>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let dynamic of dynamicArray; let i = index;">
            <td (click)="deleteRow(i)">
              <i class="fa fa-trash "></i>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input style="width:120px"  name="{{dynamic.firstName}}" [(ngModel)]="dynamic.firstName"  type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input style="width:120px" name="{{dynamic.lastName}}" [(ngModel)]="dynamic.lastName"  type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input  style="width:250px" name="{{dynamic.emailAddress}}" [(ngModel)]="dynamic.emailAddress"  type="email"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td (click)="addRow()">
              <i class="fa fa-plus "></i>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

It displays fine on opening, I can enter the three fields of data, and looking at the angular code in the TS file, I can see the populated values.  yet when I add a new row using the following code:

```
addRow() {
this.newDynamic = {firstName: "", lastName: "",emailAddress:""};
this.dynamicArray.push(this.newDynamic);
console.log('New row added successfully', 'New Row');
```

}

It blanks the values in the all previous rows.  When I look at the values in the TS file, it's properly populated.  It just is no longer displayed on the page.  Any ideas?  I've tried a number of other avenues, even added a .slice() after the add, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: View not updating on array push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813489/angular-2-view-not-updating-on-array-push)

Comment: `this.newDynamic` defined but you push `this.newDynamic2`

Comment: Typo from on of my attempts before asking the question.  I corrected it here.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. The only thing that can be optimised are,

1. declare array as empty

   dynamicArray = [];
2. push new row object directly to array

   this.dynamicArray.push({firstName: "", lastName: "",emailAddress:""});

Here is the working example,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6bt4hk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Sort of works, the display is showing the values entered into the input fields; however, the underlying array is showing blank strings.  When I try and process further, the blanks ("") are the only thing being passed.  I am really scratching my head and I cannot afford to lose more hair.  thanks for trying.

Comment: if you try to access dynamicArray you should be able to get the input values. Updated the stackblitz example to display the updated values. I guess you are trying to access the data from newDynamic.